# ESXi Virtual machine slow in datacenter

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, oracle

A virtual machine runs very fast on my HP Microserver on normal harddisks but is slow in the customers datacenter. Why?

Details:

I migrated a PHP/Oracle System (written by me) to Oracle 12, new PHP on a Win 2012 Server. The customer supplied a VM for me and I did the migration in my home office. On my home lab server (HP Microserver Gen8, Xeon 1220L and WD Red disks, no raid, 4GB for the VM) the system runs very fast. I was expecting the users to be very happy with the speedup. But:

After the customers IT department integrated the machine in their system (with SAS and high end servers, 10GB memory for the VM) the system has longer response times than on my micro server. Users say that the migration (from Win2003/32Bits) did not speed up at all and I also can prove that if I connect remotely.

Of course I use the same DB (from the same dump) as my customer.

Mainly it is database stuff as the complete business logic is written in PL/SQL on the oracle server. So I suspect the SAS being slower than my NAS disks. Of course, the SAS is used by many machines but as this is really a high end datacenter I expect their host being at least as fast as my small machine. But I cannot prove that.

As I am a programmer and no ESXi specialist, does anyone have a hint how I can find out the reason for that? The IT department states that their configuration is optimal and it must have to do with the oracle configuration i made what is nonsense in my eyes.

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Update: As nobody in the IT department was able to find issues I had the idea to check the antivirus configuration and indeed this was the reason because oracle dbf log and trc files were permanently scanned... Weird.

Comment: If I was you, I would start by asking the customer what the contention ratio is on that server. Unless you have a specific reason for pointing to the disks, in which case, it would help if you could explain that part of the context in your question. If they are pointing to your Oracle config, and all the more so on a node 'optimised' for Oracle, it might be worth asking them to either share their standard Oracle config base/template, and/or to review your config, and indicate what specifically they feel to be an issue. Any monitoring data they can provide about the setup would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must collect performance data to answer this question. Install monitoring software on your server, and have it collect metrics on CPU usage, Load Average, RAM utilization, Disk IO latency, IOwait, etc. Once you have that information you can start digging in to find where the bottlenecks are.

> Of course, the SAS is used by many machines but as this is really a
>   high end datacenter I expect their host being at least as fast as my
>   small machine.

You would be surprised what many datacenters pass off as "high end".

In general, it sounds like you're making a lot of assumptions, which aren't going to get you far. You need hard, empirical numbers and data. Only once you have that will you be able to start chasing down these performance issues.

Comment: Thanks. I will aks the IT department to run such analysis. I also suspected that overloaded high end is perhaps the reason... As soon I have numbers I will inform.